# Windows 8.1 not activating screen saver, turning off monitor, or sleep mode

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, sleep, power, screensaver

Any ideas on what would cause this? No applications that I actively run should be preventing this from happening: OneDrive, Steam, WhatPulse, puush, and f.lux. I have power options set to activate screen saver, turn off the monitor, and eventually sleep when idle. None of these trigger.

Comment: I think one of my apps, UpWork, was keeping the screen awake. After I exited it, it seemed to work. Strange because when it's active, the screen *does* go to sleep. I think it's a bug in the app.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to fix the Sleep Mode not working problem

> If Windows 8.1 refuses to sleep or won’t go in sleep mode, then this
>   post will show you how to fix the Sleep Mode not working problem
>
> Recently, we have seen how to enable or disable password requirement
>   at wake up. After upgrading one of my system running Windows 8 to
>   Windows 8.1, I have found that the sleep functionality was no longer
>   working on that system.
>
> In order to fix this issue, we need to correctly configure Windows
>   Power Plan settings. Here is the way to fix this problem.
>
> **Windows 8.1 Sleep Mode not working**
>
> 1. Press Windows Key + W and type troubleshooting in the search box. Click on the Troubleshooting from the search results so obtained.
> 2. In the following window, from the left hand side listed options, click on View all.
> 3. Moving on, pick Power from the list so available, this would launch the Power Troubleshooter.
> 4. In the Power Troubleshooter, you have to click Next option. This will start the automatic detection and fixing of issues.
> 5. When the troubleshooting has been completed, you can click Close.
>
> Now you can reboot the machine, after restart, you’ll find that the
>   issue is already fixed.

Source [Sleep Mode not working in Windows 8.1](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/sleep-mode-not-working-windows-8-1)

The above link also includes screenshots for the instructions as well as some other links that also may help.

Comment: That didn't help at all....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is a `.scr` file titled with your screensaver's name present in `System32` folder (`C:\WINDOWS\System32`).